# Copy the same file (large) into multiple server using WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I would like to copy the large file into multiple servers with in the same network programmatically. The file size varies from 500MB to 1GB.

I've implemented the logic using WCF to achieve this but it takes above 30 minutes to copy a file into one server, so it'll take some time to copy into multiple servers. I would appreciate if anyone think of better way to achieve this.

Now, I'm thinking to disconnect the user and copy the files in the background using C# windows service (and WCF) and notify the user once copy process completed. Any thoughts please?

Code mentioned below:

```
[MessageContract]
public class FileCopyRequest : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string[] DestinationFilePaths { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileContent { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileContent != null)
        {
            FileContent.Close();
            FileContent = null;
        }
    }
}

public class FileCopyService : IFileCopyService
{
    public void CopyFile(FileCopyRequest request)
    {

       foreach(var destinationPath in request.DestinationFilePaths)
       {
            var buffer = new byte[65000];
            int read;

            using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                while ((read = request.FileContent.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    destinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

  <services>
  <!--http://services.myserviceaddress.com/service.svc-->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="Services.FileCopyService">
    <endpoint address=""
    name="basicHttpStream"
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="httpLargeMessageStream"
    contract="Services.IFileCopyService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:37708/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpLargeMessageStream"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                transferMode="Streamed"
                messageEncoding="Mtom" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<!--<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>-->    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: FaceBook use BitTorrent to distribute their large binary images - it's an efficient algorithm for what you are trying to achieve (maybe your application would generate and seed a magnet file or similar?)

Comment: You have not used WCF correctly. Post the code and config. You probably need to use WCF streaming except if the server has a lot of RAM.